# computer monitor no signal + no lights on wireless mouse after power outage

Tags: windows-7, display

The power went out. 

I checked computer. 

Computer monitor and computer had power, but no signal on monitor, lights on keyboard and mouse were off.

I tried wiggling the mouse and pressing keys on key board but without any response.
I checked all the cords so as to make sure they were connected, and restarted it.
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If you get any signs of power at all, it is less likely to be the power supply, or at least only the power supply. If you purchased a cheap power supply and were not running through a surge protector, it is likely one or more things in your computer are fried. Frequently a power supply will survive a surge, but the motherboard will not as the components in it are much less resistant to variances in power.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "computer had power" which lights were on?  My first guess here would be a blown power supply.  You could try unplugging everything for a few minutes to see if that helps but I'd really suspect the power supply on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the power to the PC, does the fan inside the power supply in the back of the PC spin?  If not, it's almost certainly a bad power supply.  If it does spin, it may be a damaged system board.  In my experience if the power supply dies the rest of the system is generally ok, but if the system board goes due to a power surge, you may have all sorts of components go bad (RAM, CPU, video card).

Answer (score 0):

## [solved]

It took a brother. He switched the usb wireless mouse to the usb card instead of the direct jack in the computer, made sure the cards were connected, and restarted it.
It now works.
Brothers are awesome!

Comment: Excellent.  Those "odd" fixes are always fun.